# When will QGIS version 2 be available?

Tags: qgis

Just wondering, how close is the public release of version 2?

I do realise that I can download 1.9, but was wondering about the public version.

Comment: Sorry but this question isn't really right for here.  The QGIS mailing list is the best place to ask that.

Comment: but the real answer is it will be ready when we have squash some of the major blocking bugs, at the moment that is looking like a while away.